# What is the rsdrvx64.sys kernel mode driver?

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-8.1

EDIT: I found the culprit. Read the comments, below.

There's this rsdrvx64.sys kernel mode driver installed.

It belongs to a program called RawDisk from Eldos, but I never installed such a thing. The program itself isn't installed; just the driver.

Does anyone know what this driver does and where it could've came from? Was it installed alongside something else?

Could it be a sign of a malicious software? ESET and malwarebytes didn't find any malware.

```
- System 

  - Provider 

   [ Name]  Service Control Manager 
   [ Guid]  {555908d1-a6d7-4695-8e1e-26931d2012f4} 
   [ EventSourceName]  Service Control Manager 

  - EventID 7045 

   [ Qualifiers]  16384 

   Version 0 

   Level 4 

   Task 0 

   Opcode 0 

   Keywords 0x8080000000000000 

  - TimeCreated 

   [ SystemTime]  2014-07-30T22:24:37.242523900Z 

   EventRecordID 20433 

   Correlation 

  - Execution 

   [ ProcessID]  664 
   [ ThreadID]  8708 

   Channel System 

   Computer AD-PC 

  - Security 

   [ UserID]  S-1-5-21-2296011613-1062079115-2258569816-1001 


- EventData 

  ServiceName ElRawDisk 
  ImagePath C:\Windows\system32\drivers\rsdrvx64.sys 
  ServiceType kernel mode driver 
  StartType system start 
  AccountName
```

Comment: If you are concerned configure Windows NOT to load it upon startup and see what happens.  You can also just delete the driver.  But you really should determine which program is using it.

Comment: @Ramhound How do I configure that? I can't identify which program uses that driver. If I could, I wouldn't be here. :D

Comment: **Be specific.**  How do you configure what exactly?  Autoruns would allow you to manually disable the driver, but again, you really should determine which of your install programs is using it.

Comment: @Ramhound You said it yourself. How do I configure Windows NOT to load it (rsdrvx64.sys) upon startup? I know how to disable startup items and services, but not kernel drivers.

Comment: I require specific statements.  Anyways...Have you tried `Autoruns`?  Because I am pretty sure, I have used it, to disable kernel drivers before.

Comment: Did you ever install any file recovery software? Yodot, for example.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ahhh, yes, I think I did, not Yodot but something else, although I uninstalled it. Guess it left this driver behind. Thank you.